# get value of checkbox on form submit in razor

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have a html form and I need to get the "checked" value of some checkboxes. The problem is that when I submit the form, the data in textfields and dropdowns works fine, but all checkboxes and radiobuttons is set to not be checked.

This is my checkbox:

```
    <input name="chkbox" value="test" type="checkbox">Label text
```

This is how I try to get the value in razor on submit:

```
    if(Request["chkbox"].AsBool()){
        //its checked
    }
    else{
        //its unchecked
    }
```

If I set the checkbox to be checked by default I get a "checked" value on form submit.

It seems like when I check a checkbox it doesn't actually change it's checked state in the form?
What am I missing here?

Comment: is the `value="test"` is really what you used in the application or just for demonstrating the problem? it should be `value="true"`. and did you put the `input` inside a `form` ?

Comment: If you are using Html.BeginForm to submit your data to the action, then you can use checkbox as strongly typed way like @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Chkbox, new {@class = "hidden", @type="checkbox"}). You just need to create model for relevant data. If you can post your current code, we can try to post some answers.

Comment: The value="test" was to demonstrate, but the value was another string. Changing the value to "true" and getting the string another way solved it.